# jQuery selector for dynamic input name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a set of checkboxes that have a name like

```
form[check][..]
```

where .. is a number (id). I would have another checkbox that checked would check all the previous checkboxes, a sort of check/uncheck all. The problem is, how can with jQuery get all that checkboxes?

**EDIT 1**

this is my current html markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="form[check][1]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="form[check][2]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="form[check][3]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="form[check][..]" />

<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" />
```

Comment: Can you post more code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to the checkboxes you want checked, and select them using that class

```
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: I think this is the solution with better performances. Getting all checkboxes by dynamic names seems slow

Comment: yes but this one doesn't show the OP how to control the checkboxes from the checkAll checkbox. Though I'm not sure if finding by class is much faster than specifying they are checkboxes with dynamic name

Comment: Yes, you can combine the two and go:
    $('[name="checkAll"]').on('change', function(){
      $('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });​

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[name="checkAll"]').on('change', function(){
    $('input[name^="form[check]"]:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});​
```